# Find items that can be repeated in an xml schema using Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I want to deduce from an XML schema the couple `(parentTag, childTag)` such that it is allowed for `parentTag` to contain multiple instances of `childTag` as direct children.

Doing that by hand, I look for the `maxOccurs` attribute in the schema, look the element tag, and tag of the direct parent.

For example, from

```
<xs:complexType name="aType">
     <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="B" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="A" type="aType">
<xs:element name="ANOTHER" type="aType">
```

I should obtain the couples `(A,B)` and `(ANOTHER,B)`.

I have a working solution using XSLT to convert my schema to a list of such `(parentTag, childTag)` couples.

Is there an elegant way to do this in Java ? Which library would you recommend to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process XML schemas in Java (without XSLT), we use Xerces2 Java Parser: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/

The following packages/classes may be needed:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.*;
import org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMXSImplementationSourceImpl;
import org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.util.StringListImpl;
import org.apache.xerces.util.XMLCatalogResolver;
```

Then, the processing of an XSD file goes like this:

```
// Obtain the XML Schema implementation
XSImplementation impl = (XSImplementation)
  (new DOMXSImplementationSourceImpl()).getDOMImplementation(XMLConstants.XSD_LOADER_NAME);

// Get schema loader
XSLoader schemaLoader = impl.createXSLoader (null);

// Optional. Specify error handler
DOMErrorHandler errorHandler = ....;
DOMConfiguration config = schemaLoader.getConfig();
config.setParameter("error-handler", errorHandler);

// Optional. Specify XML catalog resolver.
// This may be needed to redirect internal DTD/schema file references
XMLCatalogResolver catalogResolver = ...;
config.setParameter("resource-resolver", catalogResolver);

String xsdURI = ...; // the location of schema file

// read schema
XSModel xsModel = schemaLoader.loadURI(xsdURI);

// PROCESS SCHEMA (here, you can do anything you want)

XSNamedMap xsMap;

// process top-level element declarations
xsMap = xsModel.getComponents(XSConstants.ELEMENT_DECLARATION);
for (int i = 0; i < xsMap.getLength(); i ++)
{
  XSElementDeclaration xsElementDecl = (XSElementDeclaration) xsMap.item(i);
  ...
}

// process top-level type definitions
xsMap = xsModel.getComponents(XSConstants.TYPE_DEFINITION);
for (int i = 0; i < xsMap.getLength(); i ++)
{
  XSTypeDefinition xsTDef = (XSTypeDefinition) xsMap.item(i);
  ...
}

// process model group definitions
xsMap = xsModel.getComponents(XSConstants.MODEL_GROUP_DEFINITION);
for (int i = 0; i < xsMap.getLength(); i ++)
{
  XSModelGroupDefinition xsGroupDef = (XSModelGroupDefinition) xsMap.item(i);
  ...
}

...
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use the `XERCES2` based on your comment but I am unable to find all elements within the ComplexType` during the parsing.
I have posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856898/how-access-any-element-from-xsd-and-get-its-datatype-and-other-related-informati If you get a chance can you please have a look at it and provide the solution if possible. Thanks a lot :)